# ios sharekit 2.0 not showing image preview when sharing image

Tags: ios, facebook, image, preview, sharekit

I'm using Sharekit2.0 to share images to facebook and twitter.

Here is the code used for sharing the image in facebook.

SHKItem *sharerItem = [SHKItem image:image title:@""];

```
SHKTwitter *sharer = [[SHKTwitter alloc] init];
[sharer setItem:sharerItem];
[sharer share];
```

But this not showing any preview of the image when sharing (like twitter is showing). just a text view to enter title for image.

My question would be: is it possible to show to image preview when sharing to facebook ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SHKItem * sharerItem = [SHKItem image:image title:@"P"];
[SHKTwitter shareItem:sharerItem];
```